# Reactive form validation - Angular & Bootstrap

Tags: angular

I am just trying to show a cross mark when the username is blank or is not with required pattern and show a tick if input entered is valid.Bootstrap is-active and is-inactive class help it. Below is the code i tried with. I only get username is undefined. I seem to have gone wrong with implementation. Could you please help rectify?

```
<form  [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Username / Email"
                  class="form-control"
                  formControlName="username"
                  [ngClass]="username.errors?'is-invalid':'is-valid'"
                  name="username"
                  id="username"
                />
    </form>
```

In ts

```
 profileForm = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$")])
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed no `username` property in your component. So yes, `username` is undefined.

The only property we know about is named `profileForm`. You can get its control named username using `profileForm.get('username')`, and you can test if this control is valid using `profileForm.get('username').valid`.

Answer (score 1):

in .ts  add

```
get userName() {
 return this.profileForm.get('userName');
}
```

in html add

```
[ngClass]="userName.hasError('pattern')" ? "is-invalid": "is-valid"
```

if you wish not to add any code in .ts file use

```
[ngClass]="profileForm.controls['userName'].hasError('pattern')" ? "is-invalid": "is-valid"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following snippet to your style sheet:

```scss
.ng-touched.ng-invalid:not(form) {
  @extend .is-invalid;
}

.ng-touched.ng-valid:not(form) {
  @extend .is-valid;
}
```